# Problema ao criar um diagrama de base de dados no Visual C# 2010 Express

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, visual-studio

Mesmo criando uma tabela chamada "People" previamente, ao criar um novo diagrama de banco de dados no Visual C# 2010 Express, não aparece nenhuma opção de tabela para eu trabalhar, nem mesmo a tabela "People" que eu mesmo criei. O que pode estar ocorrendo?

Desde já agradeço,

Comment: Vc criou a tabela no SQL? Fez a conexão com o servidor no Visual Studio?

Comment: Estou começando agora no Visual C# 2010 Express. Eu criei a tabela através do próprio SQL database que tem no Visual quando você clica em Novo item.

Answer (score 0):

**Criando uma nova base de dados SQL Server**

Para adicionar uma nova base de dados para o projeto clique no menu Project->Add new item.

Selecione Service-based Database da lista de templates disponíveis.

Digite "BaseDados" na área de nome, clique em "Add".

A ajuda de configuração de base de dados irá abrir, mas nenhum objeto estará disponível pois essa é uma nova base de dados.

Clique em "Finish" para criar a base de dados e o dataset e adicioná-los ao projeto.

**Criando novas tabelas na base de dados**

Para adicionar novas tabelas à base de dados  abra o "Server Explorer/Database Explorer" selecionando "Server Explorer/Database Explorer" no menu "View".

Expanda o nó "SampleDatabase.mdf" abaixo do nó "Data Connections". Clique com o botão direito em "Tables" e em "Add New Table". O designer de tabelas irá abrir.

**Criando um novo diagrama de base de dados**

Em "Server Explorer", clique com o botão direito em "Database Diagrams" ou qualquer diagrama na pasta.

**Importante**

Você pode usar o designer de diagrama de base de dados para atualizar base de dados em SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008, e SQL Server 2008 R2. Entretanto, SQL Server 2012 não suporta essa funcionalidade.

Escolha "Add New Diagram" no menu de atalho.
O dia "Add Table" irá aparecer.
Selecione as tabelas desejadas na lista de tabela e clique em "Add.

As tabelas são mostradas graficamente no novo diagrama de base de dados.

Você pode continuar adicionando ou deletando tabelas, modificando as tabelas existentes, a alterando os relacionamentos até o novo diagrama ficar completo.

Fontes:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763(v=vs.100).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171978.aspx

Comment: Então, ao criar o "Add New Diagram", não aparece essa opção de "Add table" logo em seguida com as tabelas desejadas.

Comment: O que aparece? Vazio?

Comment: Isso, vazio. Abre a janela do diagram em branco.